# Documents in 'Shared with everyone' folder are not showing up to users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document, mysite, onedrive-for-business

I have uploaded one document in 'Shared with everyone' folder under my site.

**My site ---> Documents ---> Shared with everyone.** (OneDrive for business)

but that document is not showing up to any user except me. can Anyone tell me documents are not showing? Is there need to configure or active something? please help.

Comment: Just check that your documents are checked in as major version if versioning is enabled..

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the **Sharing** icon:

[image]

2. Add **Everyone** from **Invite People** and give them view rights:

[image]

User should now have view access to the document.

Comment: Already checked that. its by default shared with 'Everyone'. No need to add it manually.